# What's the purpose of the cable connected on the top of the fin?

Tags: airbus-neo

[image]A321neo has on the top of the fin, backwards, a long tube, which looks like the pitot tube on the Boeing 707, but on the opposite way, and connected on it, a cable (I think because it is a test flight).
What is the purpose of each one?
Picture's credits: www.airbus.com/presscentre

Answer (score 7):

It is a Trailing Static or [Trailing Cone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trailing_cone) used in test aircraft to measure free stream values. From [Airdata Measurement and Calibration](http://www.nasa.gov/centers/dryden/news/DTRS/1995/HTML/TM-104316/index_prt.htm):

> By trailing a long tube behind the airplane, a nearly free-stream static pressure measurement can be taken. A perforated cone at the end of the tube acts as a drag device to keep the tube stable.

[image: Trailing cone]

Image from [NASA Airdata measurement and calibration](http://www.nasa.gov/centers/dryden/news/DTRS/1995/HTML/TM-104316/index_prt.htm)

It is used in test aircraft. The image below shows the trailing cone attached to the 787 dreamliner (pictured at Paris airshow).

[image: 787 cone]

Image from [flyingsquadron.com](http://www.flyingsquadron.com/forums/topic/18306-paris-air-show-2011/?page=2)

This image shows the trailing cone assembly used in 787 dreamliner.

[image: 787 Trailing cone]

Image from [airpigz.com](http://airpigz.com/blog/?currentPage=59)

The device is specified by FAA and JAA as one of several methods that can be used to perform flight calibrations. According to [FAA Advisory Circular 91-85](http://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/AC%2091-85.pdf):

> Where precision flight calibrations are used to quantify or verify altimetry system performance they may be accomplished by any of the ollowing methods. ...
>
> • Precision tracking radar in conjunction with pressure calibration of 
>   atmosphere at test altitude.
>
> • Trailing cone.
>
> • Pacer aircraft.
>
> • Any other method acceptable to the FAA or approving authority.