# What is this transport aircraft, and why does it sometimes cary an air data boom when the Soviet Buran Space Shuttle is on top of it?

Tags: aircraft-identification, supersonic

This [comment](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/44842291#44842291) in chat points to a "google search of the day" which was for [Buran](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buran_(spacecraft)) the Soviet version of the [Space Shuttle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Shuttle). Looking there I saw images of a large transport aircraft with the Buran shuttle on top. What caught my eye were some photos of  the transport aircraft with what looks like a large, orange [air data boom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_data_boom) at the end.

My understanding from [Quora answers](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-purpose-of-the-spike-sticking-out-of-the-nose-on-test-prototype-aircraft) is that these are used for supersonic flight, and I wouldn't expect this shuttle to be transported supersonically.

**Question:** What is this transport aircraft, and why does it sometimes cary an air data boom when the Buran shuttle is on top of it?

According to [this blog](http://www.thelivingmoon.com/45jack_files/03files/Buran_003.html) it is an [Antonov AN-225](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antonov_An-225_Mriya) but I don't think that is a supersonic aircraft.

[image]

[image] [image]

**above:** From [thelivingmoon.com](http://www.thelivingmoon.com/45jack_files/03files/Buran_003.html). Click for full size views.

**below:** <s>I believe this is Buran itself</s>, According to [@Hobbes' correction/comment](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/51978/what-is-this-transport-aircraft-and-why-does-it-sometimes-cary-an-air-data-boom#comment135143_51978), this is the "OK-GLI: a Buran analog (shape is correct, systems are not identical to the orbital vehicle) with 4 jet engines that was used for flight testing in the atmosphere", also with an air data boom. I've kept this here because it's actually pretty cool. From [pinterest](https://pics-about-space.com/soviet-space-shuttle?p=2).

[image]

Comment: Another question would be why the aircraft seems to have only one wing?  The right one should be visible at that angle, and in front of the tower structure...

Comment: It is indeed an An-225 (the first and only one built). A spike like this does not mean this aircraft is [supersonic](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/24414/why-when-is-the-blunt-nose-better). It can also be to put sensors as far away from the disturbe airflow (du to the big flying machine carrying it) as possible. I don't know if it is the case here, but some prototype tow such sensors to calibrate the onboard sensors.

Comment: I believe the air data sensor boom is indeed to get the sensors into undisturbed air in front of the craft, possibly to check whether its own sensors give correct readings even with the Buran on top modifying the air flow around the Antonov. Its right wing is visible behind the tower structure (different distances to left and right structures).

Comment: @jamesqf I can clearly see the right wing in the left part of the pictures

Comment: @ManuH please post that as an answer

Comment: @CptReynolds ibidem

Comment: @Federico I'll probably ask for an example or reference showing that aircraft sometimes use these circa mach 0.5, otherwise it's just speculation.

Comment: @jamesqf the right wing is behind the green structure.

Comment: @Federico It’s still speculation on my part, unfortunately. I don’t have meaningful knowledge or sources on Buran ops and transportation...

Comment: This sub-sonic aircraft has a smaller boom, and may be Russian, but I don't think it's a suitable example. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mb998.jpg

Comment: The last photo shows the OK-GLI: a Buran analog (shape is correct, systems are not identical to the orbital vehicle) with 4 jet engines that was used for flight testing in the atmosphere.

Comment: @Hobbes aha! I'd included it quickly without looking carefully, then realized it was shuttle-shaped rather than plane-shaped so made an excuse. Now I know why, those jet engines! I'll re-edit again, thanks!

Comment: @Femaref: I don't see how that can be possible.  The green structure appears to be behind the main landing gear, yet the leading edge of the wing is ahead of the gear at its root - where the person in the red shirt is standing.

Comment: @jamesqf It's quite a boggling image. There's some foreshortening since the photographer is fairly close to the front of the boom, but ya, they may have had to remove a wing (or part of it) because of the crane. *However* if you look at the first grayscale image (click to open full size) I think I can see the other wing. Again, it's the foreshortening that makes it look so weird! Looking to the extreme left of the top image, yep, there's a wing there, emerging from behind the green structure.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/wxsF7Ly.jpg?1 I've marked out one of the engines in red as well as the wing line in black. It's a very weird perspective. The structure is also quite thin, much thinner than it appears to be. some weird optic trickery going on.

Comment: @Femaref Great! I think a wide angle lens was used, which can add some non-intuitive distortion. The Buran shuttle doesn't even seem to be centered on the AN-225 (though maybe that's just me). Alternative, conspiracy theory: Photoshop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only aircraft that ever had a shuttle on top of them is [NASA's modified Boeing 747](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuttle_Carrier_Aircraft) and Russia's [Myasishchev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myasishchev_VM-T) and [the Antonov 225](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antonov_An-225_Mriya). All of them were subsonic.

The one in the picture is the high wing 6 engine Antonov 225.

The air data boom is likely to gather data for test flights for the shuttle. Subsonic craft will affect the air in front of them (that's why you can hear them coming) so putting the sensor on a boom will help put the sensors in clean air.

Comment: @uhoh not really, you want an as clean as possible reading on the sensors, subsonic craft will affect the air in front of them (that's why you can hear them coming) so putting the sensor on a boom will help.

Comment: Thanks! So if this is a one-of-a-kind aircraft and doesn't have much history flying like this, then it may be more necessary to add such an instrument since the effect of the shuttle is unknown. For the US Space shuttle, the carrier is (probably) a NASA 747 and there is probably much more experience. https://youtu.be/MhwSbeiRADA See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuttle_Carrier_Aircraft#Design_and_development and also [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/25688/12102).

Answer (score 3):

During flight testing, an aircraft's onboard instruments and sensors must be calibrated and validated. Pitot-static systems located on the fuselage are affected by the air flow around the aircraft. Some other measurement is needed to establish the relationship between actual atmospheric conditions and what the aircraft sensors measure.

One method is the boom extending from the nose. This takes measurements far enough in front of the aircraft that the air is undisturbed by the aircraft itself. Supersonic aircraft must use the boom method because the air flow behind the aircraft has been affected by the shockwaves created by the nose and other aircraft features. Especially in larger aircraft this is an expensive installation, and would interfere with the weather radar in the nose.

Another method of measuring actual conditions is a [trailing cone](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/25365/1696) extended behind the aircraft. This requires modification of the aircraft structure and is susceptible to damage.

The An-225 was built specifically to carry the Buran, so it makes sense that they would test it with the Buran on top. It would also create an especially large wake that might make a trailing cone difficult.

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed an An-225 (the first and only one built). A spike like this does not mean this aircraft is supersonic (as highlight by this [question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/24414/why-when-is-the-blunt-nose-better)). It can also be to put sensors as far away from the disturbe airflow (du to the big flying machine carrying it) as possible. I don't know if it is the case here, but some prototype tow such sensors to calibrate the onboard sensors as explained in [this video](http://www.aeronewstv.com/fr/lifestyle/comment-ca-marche/1217-ce-drole-de-cable-qui-traine-derriere-les-avions.html) (french).

Comment: Have you ever seen a sub-sonic aircraft with a boom? Both answers say it's possible, but so far no other examples have emerged. So far I can't get the video to play here either.

Comment: @uhoh the C-5 is another example that [used a boom in flight test.](https://www.thisdayinaviation.com/30-june-1968/)

Comment: @fooot excellent! (Same color too!) It would be great to see one or both images as part of an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Supplementary to @ratchetfreak's [accepted answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/51984/14213) I'd like to include an image that demonstrates air data booms are used on sub-sonic aircraft as well.

From @fooot's [comment](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/51978/what-is-this-transport-aircraft-and-why-does-it-sometimes-cary-an-air-data-boom#comment135162_51997) linking to This Day in Aviation for [30 June 1968](https://www.thisdayinaviation.com/30-june-1968/), here are photos of a prototype Lockheed C-5A Galaxy and it's first flight. This amplifies the point that the air data boom is important to establish better measurements for new aircraft or those with unusual configurations.

[image]

**above:** The prototype Lockheed C-5A Galaxy, 66-8303, at Marietta, Georgia, 30 June 1968.  (Bettmann/CORBIS) From [here](https://www.thisdayinaviation.com/30-june-1968/).

**below:** Lockheed C-5A Galaxy 66-8303 during its first flight. (Code One Magazine). From [here](https://www.thisdayinaviation.com/30-june-1968/). Click for full size.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand the downvote.